# Installer Error : Unknown error (0x80005000) Error 1001. The URL cannot be empty. Parameter name: url

Tags: asp.net, permissions, installation

I get the following error when I install a web application. I experienced this kind error only in my machine. I checked with admin privileges, but no hope.

OS - Windows 7, 64 bit

[image]

[image]

After 'Error 2', the installer is rolling back !

Comment: Run your setup with admin privileges.

Comment: @AVD I checked it with admin privileges, but no hope.

Comment: What version of IIS is there? Please read this article - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/15/tfs-2010-sp1-unknown-error-0x80005000-type-comexception-make-sure-iis-6-compat-mode-is-turned-on.aspx

Comment: @AVD Great ! It worked. Please post it as answer. I will vote and then accept it :)

Comment: Great! How did you solve? Have you turn on IIS compatibility features?

Answer (score 1):

See the following post 
http://raufthecoder.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/installer-error-unknown-error-0x80005000-error-1001-the-url-cannot-be-empty-parameter-name-url/